# Pointers to pointers passing to functions

Tags: c, pointers

Why the output is `1, 7`?

Why the `p1` doesn't change after executing functions `foo` and `bar`? As I see it, `p1` points at the same place that `n`, according to line

```
int *p1=n;
```

Then functions: `foo()`, `bar()` seems to change the place where `p1` points to `p2`, doesn't it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *p1,int *p2){
    p1=p2;
    *p1=*p2+1;

}
void bar(int**p1, int **p2)
{
    p1=p2;
    *p1=*p2+1;
    **p1=**p2+2;
}

int main() {
    int n[]={1,2,3};
    int m[]={4,5,6};
    int *p1=n;
    int *p2=m;
    foo(p1,p2);
    bar(&p1,&p2);
    printf("%d %d\n", *p1,*p2);        
}
```

Comment: Those `p1=p2` assignments kind of messes things up a bit.

Comment: `p1=p2` ìn both functions `foo` and `bar`doesn't really make sense. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Is this tutorial question?

Comment: @user013 ok, in that case, I recommend you to debug this with `printf` as I show in my answer to help you to get better understanding. Because without that, it is rather hard to understand what is going on, especially if one is not too familiar with pointers, function call, casting, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happened:

```
int n[]={1,2,3};
int m[]={4,5,6};
int *p1=n; //p1 -> n = 1, 2, 3
int *p2=m; //p2 -> m = 4, 5, 6
foo(p1,p2); //

//in foo, 
//important note: &p1 inside and &p1 outside foo are different. But p1 inside and p1 outside foo are the same
//at first both p1 inside and p1 outside still points to n
//but changes will take place soon
p1=p2; //p1 & p2 points to the same item (m) p1 -> m = 4, 5, 6; p2 -> m = 4, 5, 6. Important: p1 no longer points to n here!
*p1=*p2+1; //p1 -> m = 5, 5, 6; p2 -> m = 5, 5, 6 (add the first pointed element by 1)
//out foo

//now p1 and p2 point back to original assignment! That is &p1 and &p2 are back! So does what these p1 and p2 originally pointed to
//p1 -> n = 1, 2, 3; p2 -> m = 5, 5, 6 //note that p1 points to n again

bar(&p1,&p2);

//in bar &p1 is casted to **p1, so happen for &p2
//important note: p1 inside and p1 outside foo are the same, but &p1 inside and &p1 outside are again different
//note also that the type for p1 inside (**int) and p1 (*int) outside are different
//yet the point to the same item (p1 (outside) -> n, p1 (inside) -> n)
//then the changes immediately take place
p1=p2; //p1 & p2 points to the same item: p1 -> m = 5, 5, 6, p2 -> m = 5, 5, 6. Important: p1 no longer points to n here!
*p1=*p2+1; //pointing shift!! Pointed value of p1 (& also p2) added by 1! p1 -> &m[1] = 5, 6 p2 -> &m[1] = 5, 6
**p1=**p2+2; //the first value in the pointed value added by 2 -> p1 -> &m[1] = 7[+2 happen here], 6; p2 -> &m[1] = 7[+2 happen here], 6
//out bar

//now p1 and p2 point back to original assignment!
//p1 -> n = 1, 2, 3; p2 -> 5, 7, 6

printf("%d %d\n", *p1,*p2); //1, 7
```

Debug it like this and things will be clear:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *p1,int *p2){
    printf("foo: &p1=%x p1=%x *p1=%d &p2=%x p2=%x *p2=%d\n", &p1, p1, *p1, &p2, p2, *p2);
    p1=p2;
    printf("foo: &p1=%x p1=%x *p1=%d &p2=%x p2=%x *p2=%d\n", &p1, p1, *p1, &p2, p2, *p2);
    *p1=*p2+1;
    printf("foo: &p1=%x p1=%x *p1=%d &p2=%x p2=%x *p2=%d\n", &p1, p1, *p1, &p2, p2, *p2);

}
void bar(int**p1, int **p2)
{
    printf("bar: p1=%x *p1=%x **p1=%d p2=%x *p2=%x **p2=%d\n", p1, *p1, **p1, p2, *p2, **p2);
    p1=p2;
    printf("bar: p1=%x *p1=%x **p1=%d p2=%x *p2=%x **p2=%d\n", p1, *p1, **p1, p2, *p2, **p2);
    *p1=*p2+1;
    printf("bar: p1=%x *p1=%x **p1=%d p2=%x *p2=%x **p2=%d\n", p1, *p1, **p1, p2, *p2, **p2);
    **p1=**p2+2;
    printf("bar: p1=%x *p1=%x **p1=%d p2=%x *p2=%x **p2=%d\n", p1, *p1, **p1, p2, *p2, **p2);
}

int main() {
    int n[]={1,2,3};
    int m[]={4,5,6};
    int *p1=n;
    int *p2=m;
    int **addp1 = &p1;
    int **addp2 = &p2;
    printf("&p1=%x p1=%x *p1=%d &p2=%x p2=%x *p2=%d\n", &p1, p1, *p1, &p2, p2, *p2);
    foo(p1,p2);
    printf("&p1=%x p1=%x *p1=%d &p2=%x p2=%x *p2=%d\n", &p1, p1, *p1, &p2, p2, *p2);
    bar(&p1,&p2);
    printf("&p1=%x p1=%x *p1=%d &p2=%x p2=%x *p2=%d\n", &p1, p1, *p1, &p2, p2, *p2);
    printf("%d %d\n", *p1,*p2);
}
```

Result:

```
&p1=29fedc p1=29feec *p1=1 &p2=29fed8 p2=29fee0 *p2=4

foo: &p1=29feb0 p1=29feec *p1=1 &p2=29feb4 p2=29fee0 *p2=4
foo: &p1=29feb0 p1=29fee0 *p1=4 &p2=29feb4 p2=29fee0 *p2=4
foo: &p1=29feb0 p1=29fee0 *p1=5 &p2=29feb4 p2=29fee0 *p2=5

&p1=29fedc p1=29feec *p1=1 &p2=29fed8 p2=29fee0 *p2=5

bar: p1=29fedc *p1=29feec **p1=1 p2=29fed8 *p2=29fee0 **p2=5
bar: p1=29fed8 *p1=29fee0 **p1=5 p2=29fed8 *p2=29fee0 **p2=5
bar: p1=29fed8 *p1=29fee4 **p1=5 p2=29fed8 *p2=29fee4 **p2=5
bar: p1=29fed8 *p1=29fee4 **p1=7 p2=29fed8 *p2=29fee4 **p2=7

&p1=29fedc p1=29feec *p1=1 &p2=29fed8 p2=29fee4 *p2=7
1 7

Process returned 4 (0x4)   execution time : 0.008 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the both functions.

In the first function after its call

```
foo(p1,p2);
```

pointer `p1` points to the first element of array `n`

```
int *p1=n;
```

while pointer `p2` points to the first element of array `m`

```
int *p2=m;
```

Copies of these pointers are passed to the function as argument.

Inside the function

```
void foo(int *p1,int *p2){
    p1=p2;
    *p1=*p2+1;

}
```

after assignment

```
p1=p2;
```

pointer `p1` now points to the first element of array `m`. That is the both pointers `p1` and `p2` now points to the same first element of array `m`.

Thus in fact this statement

```
*p1=*p2+1;
```

is equivalent to

```
m[0] = m[0] + 1;
```

because pointer `p1` now points to the first element of the array and `p2` points to the first element of the arry.

As result the first element of the array was changed and now it is equal to `5`.

Take into account that when within the function `p2` was assigned to pointer `p1`

```
p1=p2;
```

the original pointers in main with the same name as the parameters were not changed because the function deals with copies of the original pointers.

When the second function was called

```
bar(&p1,&p2);
```

then you passed pointers to pointer `p1` and `p2`

```
void bar(int**p1, int **p2)
{
    p1=p2;
    *p1=*p2+1;
    **p1=**p2+2;
}
```

In this function in statement

```
    p1=p2;
```

pointer to the original pointer `p2` is assigned to variable `p1`.

Now the both varaibles contain the address of the original pointer `p2` in main.

In this statement

```
*p1=*p2+1;
```

for example expression `*p` is the value stored in the original pointer `p2` in main. This value is the address of the first element of array `m`.
Consequently expression  `*p2 + 1` is the address of the second element of array `m`

As result now the original pointer `p2` in main contains the address of the second element of array `m`.

After this statement

```
**p1=**p2+2;
```

this second element of the array was increased by 2 and now is equal to `7`.

So the effect of calling the function is two-fold. It changed the original pointer `p2`. Now it points to the second element of  array `m`. And this second element was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments in C are *passed by value*, that is, any modification applied to arguments does not make a difference to the outward arguments passed.

`foo` **assigns the copy of** `p2` **to the copy of** `p1`. Therefore, `*p1 == *p2` and

```
*p1 = *p2 + 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
++*p2;
```

incrementing `4` to `5` in the array `m`.

`bar` fails similarly. It is equivalent to

```
++*p2;
**p2 += 2;
```

incrementing `p2` from `main` by `1` and the element at that location from `5` to `7` in array `m`.

Printing both, `p1` points to `n[0]`, which is `1`, and `p2` points to `m[1]`, which is `7`.